# What affects entity encodingon output serialization when using saxon9ee?

Tags: java, saxon, oxygenxml

I have a transformation to HTML (xhtml), declared

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 

<xsl:output method="xhtml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
```

I am getting different encoding of the entities on serialization. When I output formatted text using the following code (where $converted-value is: `Jul&nbsp;28,&nbsp;2015&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;03:13:15&nbsp;p.m.&nbsp;EDT`), some times the `&nbsp;` is encoded, and other time it is not.

```
<span style="white-space:pre;">
    Jan&nbsp;05,&nbsp;2016&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;05:00:44&nbsp;p.m.&nbsp;EST
</span>
```

The difference is seen when executing in Oxygen and a Java program. From Oxygen, the entities are always output as `&nbsp;`, but in other cases (inconsistently) the output is encoded: `&amp;nbsp;` as follows.

```
<span style="white-space:pre;">
    Jan&nbsp;05,&nbsp;2016&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;05:00:44&nbsp;p.m.&nbsp;EST
</span>
```

or

```
<span style="white-space:pre;">
    Jul&amp;nbsp;28,&amp;nbsp;2015&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;03:13:15&amp;nbsp;p.m.&amp;nbsp;EDT
</span>
```

This behavior is inconsistent on the same machine, and on others.  What controls this behavior?  It seems that `disable-output-escaping` doesn't always work. How can I code so that the output is predictable?

Thanks!

Comment: I think there are copy-paste errors in your code samples (the second sample is not well-formed XML). Could you correct them please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is a sequence of six characters (&, n, b, s, p, ;) (as distinct from the single character denoted by `&nbsp;`) then it will be serialized as the 6-character string `&nbsp;` if disable-output-escaping is in force, or as the 10-character string `&amp;nbsp;` otherwise.

disable-output-escaping is in force if:

(a) you request it in the stylesheet, and

(b) the XSLT processor is performing serialization (rather than writing its output, say, to a DOM or JDOM tree). (That will depend on how the processor is invoked, so it might depend on how oXygen does things); and

(c) the instruction on which the d-o-e attribute appears is writing directly to the serializer. This won't be the case if, for example:

(i) the output of the instruction is captured in a variable

(ii) the instruction appears within a try/catch block

Generally, use of disable-output-escaping is deprecated for these kind of reasons. There is almost always a better way of achieving your desired goal.

Comment: Michael, thanks for your response.  In point of clarification, this solution has been in place for a few years now, and after upgrading to the Saxon9ee, we've started seeing differences in the serialization that is driven by Java:  transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData.getBytes("UTF-8"))), new StreamResult(strWriter) );  on some systems the &nbsp; is encoded, and some not.  We can't find any differences to account for the different serialization.

Comment: If you can produce a repro for the problem, we'll be happy to look at it.